# Creating new column in a variable that is a count of the number of observations in the variable

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to create a new column, in a variable, that is a count of the number of observation in the variable in Python. I want to make the count start from 2000. I know the code below is totally wrong but I'm trying to show what I want to do.

```
count = 2000

spyearlyclo.index = [
for value in spyearlyclo:
    print(count, value)
    count += 1
]
```

This is the outcome I want but all within a data frame.

```
Price Year
3.1   2000
3.2   2001
3.3   2002
3.4   2003
```

Comment: This is not even valid python syntax. I would suggest going through a python tutorial and learning the basics before trying to do something on your own.

Comment: Fair enough. How would you go about answering the question?